# Does shooting the second ship in the alert queue still cause an alert to take its place?

Tags: the-captain-is-dead

This is the description of shooting ships in the alert queue, on page 12:

> While the External Scanners are online, you may shoot ships that are in the visible alert queue. If you shoot the first ship in the queue (the one that will be revealed at the end of your turn) then you do not need to draw an alert card at the end of turn. If you shoot the second ship in the queue, replace it at the end of your turn when you resolve the alert for your turn.

Shooting the first in the queue just brings the next ones forward, skipping the appearance of an alert this turn, as you could expect a conveyor belt of alerts to be handled, but the rules imply shooting the **second** alert does not behave that way but simply moves all the alerts behind it up a step.  It results in an alert still appearing every turn.  My guess is this design is to make it all the more 'expensive' to consider blasting an alert that is further away from the ship.  Do I have the interpretation of the rules here right (not the reason behind it, just how they are to be followed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that when you shoot a ship that is in the first slot of the queue you are delaying it appearing for one turn. However if you shot a ship in the second slot of the queue you are preventing it form appearing at all. The difference is if you are going to delay it or prevent it from coming at all.

Comment: Very interesting. I had completely missed the interpretation of not destroying the ship in the first slot.